# background-image não funciona na section o que fazer?

Tags: css

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset=”UTF-8”>
       <meta name="author" content="Agencia de Marketing Digital Cmk">
       <meta name="description" content=" Agencia de Marketing digital em São Paulo CMK é uma empresa de marketing digital, que oferece serviços marketing digital para empresas." />
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
       <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
    <script src="scripts/seu-script.js"></script>

        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700|Roboto+Slab:400,700|Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estyles.css">
        </head>

<body>
     <header>
     <a href="index.html" target="_self"><img src= "imagens/logo-cmk.png" alt="Agencia de Marketing Digital CMK Logotipo"></a>
        <nav>

            <li><a href="index.html" target="_self">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#agencia">AGÊNCIA</a></li>
            <li><a href="#servicos">SERVIÇOS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contato">CONTATO</a></li>

        </nav>
    </header>

  <section class="hero">

  <h1>teste</h1>

   <a class="btn" href="#servicos" target="_self">PORTFÓLIO</a>

   </section>

</body>
</html>
```

======================================================================

Css:

```
/* GERAL */

* {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   font-size: 100%; 
   box-sizing: bolder-box;
   font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

} 

nav,ul{
    list-style: none;
}

a{
    text-decoration: nene;
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* FINAL GERAL */

/* HEADER */

header {

     background-color: #ffffff;
     width:100%;
     position: absolute;
     top:0;
     left: 0; 
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     align-items: center;
     padding:20px 50px; 

}

header img{
    width:150px;
}

header nav{
    display:flex;

}
header li a {
  color: #696969;
  text-decoration:none; 

}
header li  {
  margin: 0 15px;

}
header li: first-child {
  margin-left: 0;

}
header li: last-child {
  margin-right: 0;

}

/*
MEDIA QUERIES
*/

@media (max-width: 700px) {

    header {
    flex-direction: column;

}
    header img {
    margin-bottom: 15px;

}

/* hero section foto */

.hero {

     background-image: url('../imagens/fundo.jpg');


}
```

Comment: Já confirmou o caminho para a imagem ? Lembre-se que o caminho começa na pasta onde está o arquivo `css`

Comment: Pra começar, tem erro de estrutura nos `{ }` (o `@media` nao fecha)- seria bom consertar a indentação, clicar em [edit] e postar o código sem erros de sintaxe - e testar fora do `@media` ou garantir que esteja testando com menos de 700px - Trocar a imagem por um placeholder existente é bom para confirmar se o problema é o caminho, conforme mencionado pelo @isac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Além do erro que o Bacco falou da sua regra @media não estar fechada com o último `}` *e o caminho suponho que está correto*, acredito que o `position: absolute` no `<header>` também está te pregando uma peça.

Como a sua `<section>` não tem altura definida e o elemento que está acima dela tem `position absolute` a sua `section` acaba ficando por traz desse elemento e vc não enchergar. A sua `section` está ficando encoberta pelo `header`, mas a imagem na verdade está lá...

Veja que eu apenas retirei o `position: absolute` do `header` e a imagem já fica aparecendo, pois agora não fica mais por de traz do `header`. Se não resolver me fala que ai eu retiro a resposta ok.

```css
* {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   font-size: 100%; 
   box-sizing: bolder-box;
   font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

} 

nav,ul{
    list-style: none;
}

a{
    text-decoration: nene;
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* FINAL GERAL */

/* HEADER */

header {

     background-color: #ffffff;
     width:100%;
     /* position: absolute; retirar position absolute*/ 
     top:0;
     left: 0; 
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     align-items: center;
     padding:20px 50px; 

}

header img{
    width:150px;
}

header nav{
    display:flex;

}
header li a {
  color: #696969;
  text-decoration:none; 

}
header li  {
  margin: 0 15px;

}
header li: first-child {
  margin-left: 0;

}
header li: last-child {
  margin-right: 0;

}

/*
MEDIA QUERIES
*/

@media (max-width: 700px) {

    header {
    flex-direction: column;

}
    header img {
    margin-bottom: 15px;

}

/* hero section foto */

.hero {

     background-image: url(http://unsplash.it/100/100);


}
}
```

```html
     <header>
     <a href="index.html" target="_self"><img src= "imagens/logo-cmk.png" alt="Agencia de Marketing Digital CMK Logotipo"></a>
        <nav>

            <li><a href="index.html" target="_self">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#agencia">AGÊNCIA</a></li>
            <li><a href="#servicos">SERVIÇOS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contato">CONTATO</a></li>

        </nav>
    </header>

  <section class="hero">

  <h1>teste</h1>

   <a class="btn" href="#servicos" target="_self">PORTFÓLIO</a>

   </section>
```

Comment: De fato o position: absolute estava impedindo a section com o img de aparecer... acho que era isso que eu procurava obrigado a todos...

Comment: @JefersonMarcelino que bom que deu certo! Se a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como Aceita, nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas no lado esquerdo da minha resposta :) assim o site não fica com perguntas abertas pendentes sem resposta aceita.

Comment: Ops desculpas!!! Feito.

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal estou com o mesmo problema, mais conseguir dar um jeito, porem é meio chato tenho que colocar minha imagem na mesma pasta do CSS para que dê certo, mais isso é muito chato, pq eu quero deixar minha imagem em outra pasta e não na pasta do CSS.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.banner {
    background-image: url('../css/backg.jpg');
    background-color: #117050;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.banner h1 {
    font-family: 'oswald' , sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 90px;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>
    
        <section class="banner">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>texto qualquer<br/>algum texto aqui</h1>
                <span>Frases e textos.</span>
                <div class="banner--images">
                    <img src="midia/c1.jpg"/>
                    <img src="midia/c2.jpg"/>
                    <img src="midia/c3.jpg"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

</body>
</html>
```

```
insira o código aqui
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).